# When couldn't we use "in doing so" instead of "so that" or "in a way that", interchangeably?

Tags: adverbs

When couldn't we use "in doing so" instead of "so that" or "in a way that"?

And, are the following explanations correct?

1. In doing so can be replaced by when we do this or in the process.
2. By doing so can be replaced by as a result of doing this.
3. On doing so can be replaced by when/after it did this (I find this an odd sentence).
   ...

Battison suggests that even when writers
want to produce a document that is easily understood by readers, they may have
difficulty in doing so.

Battison suggests that even when writers
want to produce a document that is easily understood by readers, in a way that they may have
difficulty.

Would you please elaborate the difference between these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three have slightly different usages.

"In doing so" is typically used to mean "as a result of".  The first item directly causes the second item, but the second item might not be what was intended to happen.

"So that" also means "as a result of", but is usually used when the result is intended, instead of a coincidence.  It implies the first item was done in order to bring about the second.

"in a way that" is similar to "In doing so".

So the answers are as follows:

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yes, but you are right that this construction is not very elegant.